# Swift 4.2 unwrap issue with (??)

Tags: ios, swift4.2

have strange problem with swift 4.2 and unwrap with `??`

simple code:

```
var someVar:String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
   someOp = "print some string"

    subTitleLabel.text = "text one" + someVar ?? "unwrapped"
}
```

compiler throws error :

> Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type
>   'String'

what changed in Swift 4.2?

Comment: 1. `??` doesn't unwraps value, it defaults it if it's nil. 2. Use parenthesis

Comment: Yes it is a conditional operator, kind of abbreviated version of if ... else

Comment: its should be work u just write take another values and same unwrapped var other = someVar ?? "unwrapped"  than use subTitleLabel.text = "text one" + other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the [operator precedence](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_operators_precedence.htm).

The precedence of `+` is higher than `??` so you have to add parentheses

```
subTitleLabel.text = "text one" + (someVar ?? "unwrapped")
```

Comment: You are looking for the word *BODMAS* i think.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Yes, never heard about that. 

Comment: It is how we were taught math in primary school here in India. :D

Comment: @RakeshaShastri To be clearer, **BODMAS** stands for: **B**rackets - **O**rders (indicies, etc.) - **D**ivision - **M**ultiplication - **A**dition - **S**ubtraction. _Remember - `divsion & multiplication` have the same priority "level", just like `addition & subtraction`._